# com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream with mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade spring boot to 2.6.2 and it has in built mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0 jar .It is failing to connect to MongoDB with the below exception .I have tried a lot to resolve the issue and could not resolve .And also didn't find article with the solution . It would great help if anyone can provide the solution .Please help me

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:718) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:576) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:415) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]

2022-01-31 11:48:58.991  INFO 16080 --- [ org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
```

Java Code

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            try (InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("mongodb.pkcs12").getInputStream()) {
                keystore.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = 

    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                 keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());
    
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                 trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);
    
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
         String conns = String.format("mongodb://username:password@hostname:port/databasename?ssl=true&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&socketTimeoutMS=500000&connectTimeoutMS=500000&waitQueueTimeoutMS=3600000&serverSelectionTimeout=300000");
                    
                   MongoClientSettings.Builder mcsb = MongoClientSettings.builder();
                    MongoClientSettings mcs = mcsb
                            .applicationName("Sample-Service")
                            //.credential(mongoCredential)
                            .applyToSslSettings(sslb ->
                                    sslb.enabled(true)
                                            .invalidHostNameAllowed(true))
                            .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(conns))
                            .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                                builder.enabled(true);
                                builder.context(sslContext);
        
                            })
                            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                                    builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(86400000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                            .build();
        
                    MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(mcs);
```

Comment: Try adding maxIdleTimeMS=60000  to the conns URI

Comment: A common cause of this error is not using TLS on the client side when the server is configured to require it.  Check the server log to see if it records anything about the connection.

Comment: @R2D2 I have  already tried with maxIdleTimeMS=60000 but still it was giving same exception

Comment: You may check also timeouts in load balancers , firewalls in between your app & server , you can reduce the maxIdleTimeMS to smaller value ...

Comment: @ Joe , I have used TLS on client side but still it is failing with the same exception

Answer (score 0):

The issue happen generally when your server close the connection due to expired timeout , but your application is not yet aware , solution is to add if missing  maxIdleTimeMS so the application close the connection when it is idle before the server to identify the connection must be closed.
This is also important to release server resources.